# How to handle Unhandled Rejection from third party?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I am trying to initialize a third party component, and destroy it when the component which is using the third party library is unmounting. A lot of times I get this error: `Unhandled rejection websocket timed out`.

I have tried to add try-catch around it:

```
let initializedComponent;
useEffect(() => {
  try {
    initializedComponent = thirdPartyComponent.initMethod();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error.message);
  }
  return () => initializedComponent.destroy();
}, [])
```

And tried to add a event listener to listen to both "error" and "unhandledRejection" in the parent component which uses the third party component:
`window.addEventListener("error", handleErrorFunction)` and tried `window.addEventListener("unhandledRejection", handleErrorFunction)`, but none of this catches this.

How can I catch this "Unhandled Rejection"? I get both "WebSocket connect timed out!" and other Unhandled Rejections. I am seeking a very simple explanation.

Comment: You handle it with websocket API not with React/Client API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just `let initializedComponent` and then assign into it from the effect; that variable will not persist across the lifetime of the component, which means your component will be unable to perform teardown the way you want.

Instead, you'll need to store that reference using a hook. I suspect you can get away with something like this:

```js
let [ comp, setComp ] = React.useState()
React.useEffect(() => {
  setComp(thirdPartyComponent.initMethod())
}, [])
```

However, the problem you'll run into is that React Hooks components have no analogue for `componentWillUnmount`. That is, there's no set of values you can put into the effect's dependency list that will cause your teardown function to execute *only when your component is about to unmount*.

I think this means you'll need to use a good old class-based component. It's fine to mix Hooks-based and class-based components in the same render tree. You need a class-based component so you can execute teardown at the appropriate time.

---

There are some workarounds for this limitation, but I think they all suck really badly.

As just one example: you could add a new prop to your component, "isAboutToUnmount", which the parent component sets true before it drops the child from the tree.

The problem there is that now the parent needs to become smarter so it can predict when the child should go away, and then that process needs to be artificially staggered such that the child gets an extra re-render. I've never gone this route before, but just thinking about it makes my head hurt. Depending on how complex your parent component already is, this could make the parent a nightmare.

It is far, far simpler to switch to a class-based component, which will give you the control you need and keep the complexity within the one component of yours that wraps the third-party component.

---

Finally: have you checked the documentation and examples for this third-party component? I find it hard to believe this problem would be unique to you. I would not be surprised if they have recommended recipes for handling this; even if you don't use their exact solution, their samples will likely shed light on this.